# How to get data sent to the server through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this function that sends a request to a jsp file

```
function checkvariant() {

    if (document.form1.brandsFrom.value == '') {

    } else {

          var nam = document.form1.brandsFrom.value;
          alert(name);
             $.ajax( {
             type:"GET",
             cache:false,
             data : { name:nam},
             url:"http://localhost:8080/FindMySize/inde",             
             success:function(data) {
                $('#stage').html(data);               
             },
            cache:false,
            error:function(data)
            {
                $('#stage').html("data");
            }

          });;


    }
}
```

the data i sent through parameter name , i am receiving it in the jsp file through this code

```
function as () {  
    $('#stage').html("data");
  String nam = request.getParameter("name");
  alert(nam);}
```

But it doesnt execute . Can anyone help me so as to find why it is happening.

Comment: If you are working with .jsp I would assume you are using a Tomcat servlet container? Servlets have a `doGet()` method and a `request` object that you can get the `name` parameter from..

Comment: Where does you're passing your URL `http://localhost:8080/FindMySize/inde`. If it is to another JSP page, when you're calling the `as()` function?